# Hibernate returns error "Class path must be set or restored default"

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Java application based on Hibernate technology. I get some problems in installing my system. I am installed in my friends system. I installed JBOSS Tools (in that only Hibernate tools) in Eclipse Juno (Portable).

I just copied that folder in to my system and I run the Eclipse.exe file and it runs smooth and I am trying to create new Hibernate Configuration file in hibernate perspective.

But I got below error:

> Class path must be set or restored default

[image]

Comment: probably you missed copying some files in the config, if you are running windows, please install/copy-paste eclipse in root (like c:/ d:/), this might help.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the database driver to your classpath

1) Download the driver for your database (e.g. if you are trying to connect to MySQL you can get it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ )

2) Point to it by clicking 'Add external jars' and selecting it from the place you downloaded it to
OR
First add it to the project, and then select it by through 'Add Jars' (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

It will be because you haven't added your External jar to the class path. Add all the jars including the logger used and it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem while configuring the Jboss tool To solve this problem just Follow the below step.

1) Right Click on Hibernate file and slect the Edit Configration.

2) Go to main We Can see there three fields 1)project Select the project and select the database connection.

3)finally select the property file(jdbc.properties) and configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml) project which you want to configure.

Enjoy...