# Can't Console Configuration Hibernate in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I normally working with Hibernate in Netbeans 8.2 but since Netbeans 9, they will [stop support Hibernate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+9.0+Beta#child_ul74688306-0) so I want to try Eclipse.

I create a Maven Project with following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.codejava.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateHelloExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Hibernate Hello World Program</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I got this problem:
[image]

So I tried these solutions:

[Class path must be set or restored default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277012/class-path-must-be-set-or-restored-default):
I used the same jar/libraries, that I used in NetBeans 8.2. And it works fine.

[Eclipse/Hibernate tools error: Archive classpath entry doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862117/eclipse-hibernate-tools-error-archive-classpath-entry-doesnt-exist)
And I got this error: `Problems while loading database driverclass (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver).`

[image]

[Error in using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086368/error-in-using-hibernate). And I got this error: `jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @535b626a`. Which have no trace in Google. [image]

Does anyone have another suggestion? Thank you.

---

Other Informations:

-MacOS 10.13.6

-Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Comment: Which java version you are using also can you use eclipse kepler?also check your hibernate core version.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 JavaSE-10. I will try with eclipse kepler.

Comment: Can you use java8 and check?, if java version is not the constraint.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I tried java8 and I got this error instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8pky.png `Unable to make field private final java.util.ArrayList jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @40fdbd2f`

Comment: Can you change hibernAte version as well?

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Yes. Which version do you want me to change? Currently I have Hibernate-core 5.2.6 Final in Maven Dependencies.

Comment: Can you google and check which version is compatible with java8?

Comment: The eclipse package and release that you're using might help, along with the hibernate plug-in you're using and the method used to create the project. Also, how are you trying to create the Hibernate Console Configuration (is it from the context menu on the project?)